# wait for all jobs in a ScheduledExecutorService to finish, while allowing new jobs to be added

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule and process jobs across several threads. In my application, a job can schedule a new job (on the same `ScheduledExecutorService`), as some kind of follow-up action.

In the main thread, I want to wait until all jobs are finished, as a synchronization point. There are the `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` methods, but this disallows any running or pending job to schedule a new job. In my case, I actually want to allow this, accepting the risk that we will never finish (or hit some timeout).

How do I wait for all jobs and possibly their follow-up jobs to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by keeping track of the number of active jobs. Effectively, each job that you submit must be wrapped as follows (pseudo code):

```
increase active jobs by one
try {
    run actual job
} finally {
    decrease active jobs by one
}
```

Of course the `ScheduledExecutorService` needs to be fully encapsulated for this to work.

The next step is to find the right concurrent mechanism for this, that doesn't introduce any busy waiting.

A quick and dirty attempt using a `Lock` with a `Condition` that signals no more jobs:

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final Condition noJobs = lock.newCondition();

private long jobCount = 0;

private void increaseJobCount() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        jobCount++;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

private void decreaseJobCount() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        jobCount--;
        if (jobCount == 0) {
            noJobs.signalAll();
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void awaitNoJobs() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (jobCount > 0) {
            noJobs.await();
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

I checked some other known concurrent classes, but apart from a `BlockingQueue` / `BlockingDeque` I couldn't find any. Those take up more memory though, as you'd have to add and remove something for each job that's submitted. A `CountDownLatch` comes close but doesn't allow increasing the count.